# Extent Reports: Test Steps are getting merged in last test in Extent Reports, When executing test in Parallel

Tags: selenium, testng, extentreports

The Test Steps and Test Logs are getting merged in to the single last test.

Extent Report 3.2

Actual Reports 
Function 1 logs

[image]

Function 2 logs [Having all steps]

[image]

My Project Structure is

[image]

HomePage.java

```java
package pom;

import test.BaseTest;

public class HomePage extends BaseTest
{

    public void setClick()
    {
        test.pass("This test is pass which is in click of home page");

    }

    public void setName()
    {
        test.fail("This test is fail which is in set of home page");

    }

    public void select()
    {
        test.pass("This test is info which is in selct of home page");

    }
}
```

Test1.java

```java
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pom.HomePage;

public class Test1 extends BaseTest
{

    @Test
    public void funtion1() 
    {
        HomePage hp = new HomePage();
        hp.setName();
        hp.setClick();
        hp.select();

        test.pass("Test is Passed! ins funtion 2");

    }
}
```

Test2.java

```java
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pom.HomePage;

public class Test2 extends BaseTest
{
    @Test
    public void funtion2()
    {
        HomePage hp = new HomePage();
        hp.setClick();
        hp.select();

        test.pass("Test is Passed!");

    }
}
```

BaseTest.Java

```java
package test;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;



import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

public class BaseTest
{
    public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static ExtentTest test;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp()
    {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./Reports/MyOwnReport.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        extent.setSystemInfo("OS", "Mac Sierra");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "Jayshreekant");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Jayshreekant S");

        htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(false);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("AutomationTesting.in Demo Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("My Own Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        //htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startTest(Method m)
    {
        test = extent.createTest(m.getName(),"This is the description of Test" + m.getName());

    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result)
    {
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test case FAILED due to below issues:", ExtentColor.RED));
            test.fail(result.getThrowable());
        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
        }
        else
        {
            test.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" Test Case SKIPPED", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
            test.skip(result.getThrowable());
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown()
    {
        extent.flush();
    }
}
```

testngall.xml

```xml
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Test 1 ">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.Test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 2">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.Test2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

So this is the entire project code structure, I am getting the logs appending in last test

Comment: Can you please post your valuable comments ? @Anshoo

Comment: your tests are not thread safe. You have to ThreadLocal class instance variable.  something like this, private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
public static ExtentTest test;
```

Since this is static there is only ever one instance of it.  When you run your tests in parallel this `@BeforeMethod` is called twice.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void startTest(Method m)
{
    test = extent.createTest(m.getName(),"This is the description of Test" + m.getName());

}
```

The second time it is called the first test probably hasn't finished, but it is still referencing the test object so you will get the output of the second test and some parts of the first test that had no completed running at the point the `@BeforeMethod` was called.
You are going to need to rewrite your code to not use a static `test` object.

Comment: If you remove static keyword, It is throwing NullPointerException in the HomePage.java at line `test.pass("This test is pass which is in click of home page");` , This did not work as well.

Comment: It is the basic functionality of TestNG, The baseclass methods will execute everytime you execute the tests, There is no separate instance required, The beforemethod instance will create a new test instance every time. This is how extent reports work.

Comment: TestNG is not Magic, it can't create multiple instances of objects that are defined as a single object in your base class

Comment: Yes, If you put code in the before's annotation, It will create on runtime.

Comment: It will assign something new to the object every time the `@BeforeMethod` or `@BeforeClass` annotation is called.  It categorically will not create multiple instances of a static object.

Comment: Do you have any alternative to achieve this? @Ardesco

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep your parallel execution thread safe, your ExtentTest have to use ThreadLocal class instance variable. try,

```
private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the class where you create tests, you can make this a child class of the class where you define extent report classes and variables. Now in the child class (having tests) you can create multiple Extent Test instances.

So create a new instance for every new test